# c++ creating templated objects programmatically

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Suppose I want to instantiate many objects that come from a templated class (something like std::bitset) from bitset<1> to bitset<10>.

```
for (size_t i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  std::bitset<i> my_bitset;
  // do stuff with it...
}
```

obviously this won't compile because i is not a literal or a `constexpr`.

Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking everything *template metaprogramming* possible in my head but I can't figure this one out. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Make your own bit vector class, it would be relatively simple to do as a wrapper around `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: I think you're looking for [`dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Comment: What's your purpose in forcing the instantiations?  What functionality are you trying to get?

Comment: I am not using bitset (this was just to simplify the example)

Comment: Tony, I have a few classes "templatized" much in the same fashion as the std::bitset (hence why I chose it as an example). I am writing tests for these classes, and I'd like to have my tests run some extension of the possible instantiations of the class.

Comment: A template is not a class at all, only its specialisations are classes. Any failures arising out of the result of using a template class will do so at compile time.

Can you not just test a handful of specialisations? If the logic varies between specialisations, perhaps this is a situation which doesn't warrant a template class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, as you realized, to use a runtime variable as a template parameter; however should you know the list of values to use at compile-time, then you can indeed have a way to invoke tests for each element of this list.

```
template <template <size_t> class F>
void run() {}

template <template <size_t> class F, size_t H, size_t... Tail>
void run() { F<H>()(); run<F, Tail...>(); }
```

Then it is just a matter of defining `F`:

```
template <size_t N>
struct BitSetPlay {
    void operator()() {
        std::bitset<N> b;
        b.flip();
        std::cout << b.to_ulong() << "\n";
    }
};
```

[Putting it altogether](http://ideone.com/qzA8kH):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

template <template <size_t> class F>
void run() {}

template <template <size_t> class F, size_t H, size_t... Tail>
void run() { F<H>()(); run<F, Tail...>(); }

template <size_t N>
struct BitSetPlay {
    void operator()() {
        std::bitset<N> b;
        b.flip();
        std::cout << b.to_ulong() << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    run<BitSetPlay, 1u, 2u, 3u, 4u, 5u, 6u, 7u, 8u, 9u, 10u>();
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: this assumed a possibly discontiguous list, if it is a range you wish for then you can do without variadic templates by simply keeping track of the bounds.*

Comment: yes it is the case that you know all the numbers to be tested at compile time, this looks interesting. I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, because templates are a compile-time only concept. You can't use runtime data to declare templated instances.

Template arguments have to be types, or compile-time constants.

Comment: @Carneiro Yes, template-metaprogramming is just way of using (or abusing some would say) the compiler to generate code for you, but it's still all done during compilation.

Comment: @Carneiro Best template metaprogramming program ever written was the first. It produced the prime number series in the *compiler error messages*. Proof that template metaprogramming happens at compile time.

Comment: this is very misleading - you definately can do this with recursive templates instead of using a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Something like (not tested):

```
template<int N>
struct InstantBS
{
    std::bitset<N> bs;
    InstantBS<N-1> next;
};

template<>
struct InstantBS<0>
{
};

template struct InstantBS<10>; //instantiate bitset<1> to bitset<10>
```

**UPDATE**: Well, I have tested it, and it does not work! The problem is that the members of `InstantBS` are not implicitly instantiated. And unfortunately, explicit instantiation  must occur at namespace level, so you cannot force a explicit instantiation from another explicit instantiation. Unfortunately, template namespaces are not invented yet...

The closest think I can devise is this, doing manual instantation of any member of the `bitset` you need:

```
template<int N>
struct InstantBS
{
    void DoThings()
    {
        std::bitset<N> bs;
        bs.set();
        bs.reset();
        bs.flip();
        //any other operation you want to instantiate

        InstantBS<N-1> next;
        next.DoThings();
    }
};

template<>
struct InstantBS<0>
{
    void DoThings()
    {
    }
};
template struct InstantBS<10>; //instantiate bitset<1> to bitset<10>, more or less
```

You can check that the requestet members of the bitsets are actually instantiated:

```
$ g++ -c test.cpp
$ objdump -t test.o | c++filt | grep bitset
```

Comment: Beat me to it - only thing I was doing was abstracting out bitset and using template<typename T, int N> instead - so it can be re-used for all the classes he had.  Was also considering taking another template arg  a driver as a functor that took T as an arg. -- so +1 for saving me the trouble of writing all that :)

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: I'm afraid it does not work as expected, because members of the explicit instantiated class are not explicitly instantiated. See my updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

see docs:
The size of a bitset is fixed at compile-time (determined by its template parameter). For a class that also optimizes for space allocation and allows for dynamic resizing, see the bool specialization of vector (vector).